# Is high logical read terrible for performance? AFAIK this is reading from memory, which is fast

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, entity-framework

I have database query that seems to have abnormally high logical read (refer below).

I am not a DBA, but from the plan it seems pretty optimized to me? There are 2 index scans but the cost isn't that bad IMHO, just **14%** and **4%** respectively.

I am **more interested in addressing the seemingly abnormally high logical reads** (relative to the other queries).

**The execution plan for this query**, pasted into Paste The Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJj8s6L1a

[image: high logical read]

This is the query generated by Entity Framework.

```sql
/*
This query text was retrieved from showplan XML, and may be truncated.
*/

SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[UserName], [a].[Email], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[FullName], [a].[StaffNo], [a].[Division], [a].[Department], [a].[Section], [a].[ModifiedDate], [a].[UserType], [a].[UserRegistrationStatus], [a].[Company], [a].[Remark]
FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]
WHERE ((([a].[IsActive] = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND ([a].[IsDeleted] = CAST(0 AS bit))) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [AspNetUserClaims] AS [a0]
    WHERE ([a].[Id] = [a0].[UserId]) AND (([a0].[ClaimType] = 'tenantId') AND ([a0].[ClaimValue] = @__currentTenantId_0)))) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [UserAuthorizedArea] AS [u]
    INNER JOIN [AspNetRoles] AS [a1] ON [u].[RoleId] = [a1].[Id]
    WHERE ((([u].[IsDeleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)) AND ([u].[TenantId] = @__ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_0)) AND ([a].[Id] = [u].[UserId])) AND ([a1].[RoleType] = @__request_SearchUserModel_RoleName_1))
ORDER BY [a].[Id]
OFFSET @__p_2 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_3 ROWS ONLY
```

Any idea **how this query can be optimized further** to reduce the logical read?

**Number of executions** : 1,883

**Total durations (ms)** : 809,714 ms

**Average query duration** : 809,714 / 1,883 = 430 ms

[image: More stats]

Comment: You should upload the actual execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and link it in your Post. It contains a lot more information encoded in it that a screenshot doesn't show. Also FWIW, the costs in an execution plan are estimates and based on very old standards, making them mostly useless when analyzing the bottleneck in an execution plan. There are definitely a few improvements that can be made to your query at a quick glance.

Comment: Uploaded it into Paste The Plan as suggested @J.D.

Comment: Average 2,476,721 reads per execution then. Which is quite a bit more than the actual execution plan shown. I presume it gets into the millions for later offsets?

Comment: @MartinSmith I just hover my mouse to get the number, I hope I got it correctly.

Comment: I'm sure you did. It seems quite a strange query to be running so regularly TBH (paginated list of all users meeting some criteria rather than just checking values for a specific user) - is this for some sort of admin screen? In the plan you have given it estimates 488.041 rows in one part (actual142022) and so ends up executing 142022 seeks on AspNetRoles totalling 275159 reads

Comment: TBH I am not entirely sure why the app is querying this so often, but that subject to another investigation. I am checking that as well currently.

Comment: The pagination using `OFFSET @__p_2 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_3 ROWS ONLY` is probably the worst part of this query. If you instead switch to using Keyset Pagination, you would probably see far less rows being read unnecessarily, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519518/is-there-any-better-option-to-apply-pagination-without-applying-offset-in-sql-se/70520457#70520457

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Charlieface, I understand why the OFFSET approach is not good for performance, but as of now I am trying to avoid altering the frontend. Will use Keyset in future codes.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the direct question, if high logical reads are bad for performance, I would answer yes. EDIT, ... Maybe, it depends.  I would definitely pay attention to them.

There are a lot of considerations for what queries to focus on when tuning an entire system.  In my experience, looking for ones with high logical reads, especially when they aren't tied to reports or other analytics is one of them.

A partial list, in no particular order:

1. Queries that users are actually complaining about.
2. High Duration
3. High CPU
4. High execution frequency
5. High Logical Reads

Addressing High Logical Reads specifically:

You may be able to store the entire table in memory and thus access it quickly through the buffer cache, but that means that something else CANNOT be in memory.  If you are in a memory contentious server, then that contributes to a low Page Life Expectancy, which in turn means higher disk I/O than necessary.

Whether those logical I/O comes from the buffer cache or disk, it still means the engine had to crawl all of those pages to serve the data.

Would I spend time tuning this query (either through indexes or query re-writes)... maybe.  Queries generated through an ORM like Entity Framework can be difficult to tune, and this one appears to be needing a re-write rather than additional indexes.  If you are short on memory then I would definitely spend a little time looking at indexes to see if any would help, but it might not matter if they are intent on using offset.  Given that... a users table is probably relatively small.

One possibility for you might be to look at table compression as a means of reducing the footprint that the table requires without requiring a large re-working of that screen.

Good luck.

Comment: I figured it is not much juice I can squeeze further out of this query. So, I implemented Entity Framework second level cache instead (with 1 minute cache timeout). This will greatly reduce database load during peak hours. So far seems ok, will keep monitoring for a week or so.

Answer (score 0):

reading from buffer cache is faster that reading from disk. That's fine but Reading little from buffer is better than read a lot as you spare buffer cache for other activities. If you can lower the amount of logical IO with an index or reshaping an existing index having it more focused on your query could reduce the read amount.

Try also to verify if your parameters data types match the columns data types.

Also doing index maintenace could reduce the IO. The same for removing fill factor from indexes.